# Add channel to category by name

Tags: javascript, move, categories, channel, discord.js

```
    var server = message.guild;
    for (var i = 0; i < server.channels.array().length; i++) {
        server.channels.array()[i].delete();
    }

    server.createChannel("Text Channels", "category");
    server.createChannel('general', "text");
```

I am trying to make the text channel 'general` go into the category 'Text Channels'

**All the solutions** I have found **rely on you knowing the categories id**. I was wondering **if there is a way I could get the category id**, or else move general into "Text Channels" simply by its name.

NOTE:: Currently I am thinking of something along these lines to get the category id:

```
var categoryID = server.categories.find("name","Text Channels");
```

Then to use

```
server.channels.find("name","general").setParent(categoryID);
```

Comment: And why isn't the mentioned code working? Please give us an proper example of the things that you've tried so I can help you with this. We don't offer a code-writing-service.

Comment: @KoenHollander The code is working, I am merely asking how to move general into text channels. I haven't been able to find anywhere that works. If this is considered spam, are you aware of any sites where I can ask?

Comment: I see, I'm sorry. I've found something that will help, you can set a channel parent: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2644

Comment: @KoenHollander That seems to be working fine, except it only works for channel id's. If you know of any way to get a category id that would be great. I know how to get channel id's, just not categories. Sorry if I am wasting your time

Comment: I don't see a problem, the code at the bottom works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: A category is a channel for discord.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`GuildChannel.setParent()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setParent). Please keep in mind that categories are considered as channels by Discord: `CategoryChannel` extends `GuildChannel`, so you can check the type with [`GuildChannel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type)

To assign an existing channel:

```
let category = server.channels.find(c => c.name == "Text Channels" && c.type == "category"),
  channel = server.channels.find(c => c.name == "general" && c.type == "text");

if (category && channel) channel.setParent(category.id);
else console.error(`One of the channels is missing:\nCategory: ${!!category}\nChannel: ${!!channel}`);
```

To create a new channel:

```
server.createChannel("general", "text")
  .then(channel => {
    let category = server.channels.find(c => c.name == "Text Channels" && c.type == "category");

    if (!category) throw new Error("Category channel does not exist");
    channel.setParent(category.id);
  }).catch(console.error);
```

---

**Edit: discord.js@v12**
The only thing that changes is that you have to use the [`GuildChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) for everything.

```js
let category = server.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "Text Channels" && c.type == "category"),
  channel = server.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "general" && c.type == "text");

if (category && channel) channel.setParent(category.id);
else console.error(`One of the channels is missing:\nCategory: ${!!category}\nChannel: ${!!channel}`);
```

```js
server.channels.create("general")
  .then(channel => {
    let category = server.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "Text Channels" && c.type == "category");

    if (!category) throw new Error("Category channel does not exist");
    channel.setParent(category.id);
  }).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: that code is returning [][][][] DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
[][][][][]

more info: https://pastebin.com/9dy7tNgK

Comment: That is only a DeprecationWarning, the error is just below: it says that the channel does not exist (you didn't create the channel before executing this code). I will update my answer to include channels' creation.

Comment: This is no longer available in current Discord.JS version

Comment: @MattWestlake This answer is from 2018, I'll update it with the methods for discord.ks@v12

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but here's the way to get the channel_id :

- right click on the channel to open the menu
- click on Copy id (in the bottom of the menu)