# Move channel from Category 1 to Category 2 with roles

Tags: discord.js, discord.py

how do i make the channel move category using roles?

example:

Category 1 (roles 1)
My Channel

Category 2 (roles 2)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is not a site where you can request that other people write code for you but a site for answers if your code doesn't work. So if you have tried anything to solve your question then please include it.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please take the [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add channel to category by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479542/add-channel-to-category-by-name)

Comment: Also, you tagged this question both `discord.js` *and* `discord.py`. What do you want??

Answer (score 0):

as people have pointed out in the comments, this is a really bad question, as stack overflow is for help with issues, not help for writing code. Also try to make your question more descriptive, what have you tried, etc.

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean since the question's less than 20 words long, but moving a channel inside a category should be done like this:

```
let category = server.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "My Category" && c.type == "category"),
  channel = server.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "text-channel" && c.type == "text");

if (category && channel) channel.setParent(category.id);
```